# Ordered list with M2M for different models?

Tags: django, django-models

How can I create a List model that has many-to-many relationships with multiple different models in a specific order?

E.g. models.py

```
class ItemA(models.Model):
    ???

class ItemB(models.Model):
    ???

class List(models.Model):
    ???
```

Shell:

```
a1 = ItemA.objects.create()
a2 = ItemA.objects.create()

b1 = ItemB.objects.create()
b2 = ItemB.objects.create()    

list1 = List.objects.create()
list2 = List.objects.create()

# ??? Some code here that can associate 
# a1, a2, b1, b2 (in that order) with list1 and 
# a1, b1, a2, b2 (in that order) with list2

# so that list1.items can return a1, a2, b1, b2 (in that order)
# and list2.items can return a1, b1, a2, b2 (in that order)

# and something like a1.list will return list1 and list2
```

Is this even possible?

Edit: ItemA and ItemB are very different so setting them up as proxy, inherited, and/or polymorphic model is not feasible.

Comment: Although you say `ItemA` and `ItemB` are very different at the least they have one thing in common that they can be present in a `List`. So you can say `ItemA` is a (let's say) `ListItem`. Hence the logical solution being a one to one field from `ItemA` to `ListItem` (similar for `ItemB`). Plus order by pk of `ListItem` if you want to consider order of insertion or a custom order field or similar.

Comment: So there would be an '''item''' One to One field to '''ListItem''' on the '''ItemA''' and '''ItemB''' models and '''ListIem''' would have a ForeignKey relationship to List?

Comment: No, you want a many-to-many relationships you said right? So their would be a m2m between `List` and `ListItem` (a foreign key would instead mean a many to one instead).

Comment: Sorry, just edited my original reply. Wouldn't ```ListItem``` be a ForeignKey relationship to ```List``` as the ordering is distinct? E.g. The ```ListItem``` for ```a2``` in ```list1``` has an order of 2 but the ```ListItem``` for ```a2``` in ```list2``` would need to have an order of 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a GenericForeignKey. More info on this reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/djangolearning/comments/mm75l1/ordered_list_with_m2m_for_different_models/